# Why am I getting error on my browser after my view changed to other view (angular)?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope, angularjs-routing, node-webkit

I have problem with my ng-view. When I successful change to other view, Am getting error from browser**(node-webkit):

There is error:

```
Error {stack: (...), message: "Not running"}message: "Not running"stack: (...)get stack: function () { [native code] }set stack: function () { [native code] }
```

Whe you collapse it:

```
 __proto__: dangular.js:11594 
(anonymous function)
angular.js:8544 
(anonymous function)
angular.js:14704 
Scope.$broadcastangular.js:14322 
Scope.$destroyangular-route.js:913 
cleanupLastViewangular-route.js:946 
(anonymous function)
angular.js:6953 publicLinkFnangular.js:7093 boundTranscludeFnangular.js:7749 controllersBoundTranscludeangular-route.js:939 
updateangular.js:14702 
Scope.$broadcastangular-route.js:622 
(anonymous function)
angular.js:13170 processQueueangular.js:13186 
(anonymous function)
angular.js:14383 Scope.$evalangular.js:14199 Scope.$digestangular.js:14488 Scope.$applyangular.js:9646 doneangular.js:9836 completeRequestangular.js:9777 requestLoaded
```

There are routes:

```
  $routeProvider.when("/test2", {
        templateUrl: "components/home/homeTest2.html",
        controller:'home'
    });
    $routeProvider.when("/bindingTest", {
        templateUrl: "components/binding/bindingTest.html",
        controller:'bindingController'
    });
```

It is application of home automation which handle udp connection to zigbee and handle data from zigbee.

Pls, if anyone have idea what is problem pls help so i can think about how i can solve it.

Sry if english was bad...